# Removal of rows with a duplicate value in a column based on a condition from another column - Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have data from a CSV file read into Pandas dataframe (all cells have string type, NaN:s are replaced with "" already) with some duplicate values that I need to get rid of.

A sample input CSV:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,rrrrr,fff
A,,ffff
B,rrr,fffff
C,,ffffff
D,rrrrrrr,ffff
C,rrrr,fffff
E,rrrrr,fff
C,,kkkkk
```

I need to remove those rows that have a duplicate value in Col1 and where Col2 value is "".
So the desired result shall look like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,rrrrr,fff
B,rrr,fffff
D,rrrrrrr,ffff
C,rrrr,fffff
E,rrrrr,fff
```

I use the following line of code to de-duplicate:

```
my_df = my_df.loc[(my_df["Col2"] != "") | ~my_df["Col1"].duplicated()]
```

Which removes some but not all desired rows with the duplicates in Col1. If such a "duplicate row" comes before a rowsthat shall be kept (which as a non-empty Col2), it will not be removed, and my code gives a result like this:

```
Col1,Col2,Col3
A,rrrrr,fff
B,rrr,fffff
C,,ffffff
D,rrrrrrr,ffff
C,rrrr,fffff
E,rrrrr,fff
```

As you see, the duplicate for A is removed correctly, while for C one of the duplicates (the one which occurs before the row that shall be kept) stays.

Any advice how to fix? I might be missing something right under my nose here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the count of each value in `Col1` and then use that `computed_count` and [`pandas.Series.isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html) for getting waht you want.

```
df['cnt_col1'] = df.groupby('Col1')['Col1'].transform('count')
m = (df["Col2"].isna()) & (df["cnt_col1"]>1)
df_new = df[~m].drop('cnt_col1', axis=1)
print(df_new)
```

Or without groupby:

```
cnt = dict(df['Col1'].value_counts())
cnt_col1 = df['Col1'].map(cnt)
m = (df["Col2"].isna()) & (cnt_col1>1)
print(df[~m])
```

Output:

```
  Col1     Col2   Col3
0    A    rrrrr    fff
2    B      rrr  fffff
4    D  rrrrrrr   ffff
5    C     rrrr  fffff
6    E    rrrrr    fff
```

Comment: Thank you! This really does the trick. I had considered a workaround that involves reversely sorting the dataframe by Col2 so that the rows with empty Col2 would be the last (a hack that would work since the first occurrence would be the one I need). But your suggestion is cleaner!